# How do I remove a substring from system_profiler with a posible if then?

Tags: terminal

In short, I’m writing a script that will check if a computer is a MacBook Pro or a MacBook Air and then I want to use the output as a variable.

Using

```
system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | grep “Model Name”
```

I can get Model Name: MacBook Pro but all I need is either “MacBook Pro” or “MacBook Air”

`-oP` in `grep` gives me an error. Another idea was to use find but I’m unsure how I’d use find if I’m not searching an actual file.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using `awk` with `system_profiler` :

```
 system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | awk -F ': ' '/Model Name/ { print $2 }'
```

We change the field separator to `: <space>` then search for a line with Model Name in it and print the second field. Or instead of using a pipe use process substitution to feed `awk`

```
awk -F ': ' '/Model Name/ { print $2 }' < <(system_profiler SPHardwareDataType)
```